# Exception Resource Temporarily unavailable while firing 50 requests for checking snapshot exits or not

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

I have created snapshots of 50 disks because gcloud does not allow snapshots with similar name.  Before firing snapshot create I was checking if snapshot exists or not in gcp and fired 50 requests simultaneously and almost 5-6 requests failed with below exception.

```
snapshots().get(project=self.project, snapshot=name).execute()
```

exception :

```
File "/tmp/cloudpoint/libs/gcp/lib/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/cloudpoint/libs/gcp/lib/googleapiclient/http.py", line 837, in execute method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
File "/tmp/cloudpoint/libs/gcp/lib/googleapiclient/http.py", line 163, in _retry_request resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/cloudpoint/libs/gcp/lib/oauth2client/transport.py", line 175, in new_request redirections, connection_type)
File "/tmp/cloudpoint/libs/gcp/lib/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request connection_type=connection_type)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1607, in request (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1349, in _request(response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1305, in _conn_request response = conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 756, in recv return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 643, in read v = self._sslobj.read(len)
error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Resource temporarily unavailable" means that the Compute Engine API was not available to fulfill the request. Since you made 50 simultaneous requests to check if the snapshots exist, the Compute Engine API was not able to handle all 50 of the requests at the same time so it timed out for 5-6 of the 50 requests.